# Complement of the product of Bernstein set and meager set

Tags: set-theory, transfinite-recursion, transfinite-induction

Assume $M\subset\mathbb R$ be a meager set with cardinality $\mathfrak c.$ I want to construct a Bernstein set $B$ such that $\mathbb R\setminus(B\cdot M)$ has cardinality $\mathfrak c$ , $B\cdot M=\{b\cdot m\mid b\in B,  m\in M\}$. It is an easy transfinite induction to construct a Bernstein set but I want an extra condition.

I do not know if I need a set-theoretical assumption for that or not. More precisely, It is possible or not. I hope I can find an answer or hint since I spent  plenty of time but I did not get any thing at least  possible or not.

Comment: I think under CH (or maybe even just MA) the standard transfinte induction idea would be doable.  But without I don’t see it yet.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Thank so much for your comment. I know how to do Bernstein set by using the transfinite induction. I have little knowledge about $\text{MA}$. Could you please show at least the inductive step in the transfinite induction. I spent plenty of time thinking but I did not get, Thank you again.

Comment: The essential part of MA that you need is that any union of $<\mathfrak{c}$ many meagre sets is meagre, which allows the induction to go on.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma,  I know that $\text{MA}$ implies the union of less than $\mathfrak c$ meager set but how I can state to make sure the complement would be 4\mathfrak c$

Comment: At each stage pick a point of the complement to be as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, sorry my last comment  has a lot of  typos. I will write again. $M=\{m_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$. and $\{P_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ set all perfect subset of $\mathbb R$. By induction on $\xi<\mathfrak c$ choose sequences $\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$, $ \{y_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ , and $\{z_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ such that $x_\xi,y_\xi\in P_\xi\setminus(\{x_\zeta\colon \zeta<\mathfrak c\} \cup\{y_\zeta\colon \zeta<\xi\})$ and $z_\xi\in R\setminus\{\frac{x_\zeta}{m_\zeta}\colon \zeta<\xi\}.$ Now, let $B=\{x_\xi\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, even in my construction I am not sure how can possible to choose a point when less than meager set. since ,meager set may be a perfect. How can we ensure that ? am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I answered my question. Surprisingly, the answer is very simply even though  I spent a lot of time thinking to find such  function. There answer is

**No Bernstein can be found with this property**

Let $M$ be compact nowhere dense prefect set. For contradiction, let $B$ be a Bernstein set such that $\mathbb R\setminus(BM)$ has cardinality $mathfrak c.$ Now,  pick $x\notin BM$. Notice that $xM^{-1}$ is uncountable closed set( cantinas a perfect set) and $$xM^{-1}\cap B=\emptyset$$ which is a contradiction   since $B$ is a Bernstein set.

Answer (score 0):

My idea wold be to do this, following up on my comments: assume MA. We are given a meagre set $M$ and want to construct a Bernstein set $B$ such that $\Bbb R\setminus M\cdot B$ is size continuum.

Enumerate all relevant perfect subsets of $\Bbb R$ as $\{P_\xi: \xi < \mathfrak{c}\}$.

We will construct points $\{(x_\zeta, y_\zeta, z_\zeta)\mid \zeta < \mathfrak{c}\}$  by transfinite recursion; at stage $\xi < \mathfrak c$ we pick distinct

$$x_\xi, y_\xi \in P_\xi \setminus (\{x_\zeta \mid \zeta < \xi\} \cup \{y_\zeta \mid \zeta < \xi\} \cup \{0\})\tag{1}$$

while ensuring

$$z_\xi \notin \bigcup\{ M \cdot x_\zeta\mid \zeta < \xi\}\tag{2}$$

$(1)$ follows the standard construction of a Bernstein set and works for the same reasons, while $(2)$ can be done as the sets $M \cdot x_\zeta$ are also meagre and so fewer than $\mathfrak{c}$ cannot cover $\Bbb R$ by MA.

In the end $B:=\{x_\xi: \xi < \mathfrak{c}\}$ will be Bernstein, and $(2)$ ensures the condition about $\Bbb R\setminus M \cdot M$ as the $z_\xi$ witness the size of it (I think); I see that I haven't built in assurances for them to be all distinct yet... So this is almost OK, but not quite.

If a condition like MA is at all necessary I do not know yet. It's late and I'll call it a night.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, In order to finish, we need to make sure that $z_\xi\neq x_\zeta M$ for all for all $\zeta< \xi<\mathfrak c.$ In case, $\zeta<\xi$ it ensured by $2$. The difficulty that  I have isto ensure it when $\xi<\zeta$. We can avoid  in $1$ the folllowing set $\bigcup \{z_\zeta M^{-1}\colon \zeta<\xi\}.$ Notice that $M^{-1}$ is a meager set. The problem is that it might be perfect . So, we do not have a control  to choose $x_{\xi}$

Comment: Henno Brandsma, I have a doubt if the transfinite induction will work for this problem.

Comment: @00GB You're probably right. But I think your way also fails..

Comment: Henno Brandsam, yeah, since my way is also by transfinite induction. It might repost again by this solution may be someone who fixed or show the transfinite induction would not work